# How to minimize tolls when driving past NYC

Tags: usa, driving, routes, tolls

When driving up or down the Eastern seaboard  GPS and navigation apps all seem route me through New York City, leaving me to deal with the exorbitant bridge tolls. My most recent trip cost me over $50 in tolls, mostly because the GPS insisted on sending me into, then out of, NYC. Seeing as how the high tolls are presumably meant to deter city traffic, you'd think there would be a way for drivers to opt out of driving through the city. But of course, asking Google Maps or Waze to avoid tolls gives me the completely toll-free route, which adds many unnecessary hours to my trip by avoiding every toll along the way. So, my question is: how can I avoid or minimize the NYC tolls if I just want to go past New York and not enter it?

Comment: decide how far out from NYC you might want to detour from and to, and set your start/end points there.  Then navigate to those points using tolls on, then switch it around NYC, then switch it back again

Comment: What’s your specific route?

Comment: @Midavalo that looks like a (good) answer to me

Comment: Shame Wazes does not know the cost of all tolls and provide a way  for you to say how much your time is worth.

Comment: "high tolls are presumably meant to deter city traffic" No, they're meant to make money. Especially from drivers like you.

Comment: @user91988: There's no reason why both aspects can't be intentional.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: The MTA and Port Authority are insufficiently competent.

Comment: Get out and walk.  Rent a new car when you're past NYC.

Comment: Depends on how more fuel you will consume. With European hefty prices on fuels, maybe what you save on toll is burned in gasoline.

Comment: @J... depending on traffic, your suggestion could well be faster! I once spent 45 minutes going 3 blocks with my parents as we exited the Lincoln Tunnel. When I lived in the city with my grandparents for a summer, the bus, the train and walking all got me to work in the same amount of time. My mode of travel was determined by the weather and if I felt like spending the cash to sit.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have to cross the Hudson River somewhere, so its bridges are natural choke points.  The three closest to, but not entering, New York City are:

- [New Tappan Zee Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tappan_Zee_Bridge_(2017%E2%80%93present)) on I-87/I-287/NYS Thruway, toll $5.00 eastbound
- [Bear Mountain Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bear_Mountain_Bridge) on US-6/US-202, toll $1.50 eastbound
- [Newburgh-Beacon Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newburgh%E2%80%93Beacon_Bridge) on I-84, toll $1.50 eastbound.

The bridges further north would likely be too far out of your way (the next is the Mid-Hudson bridge, 75 miles north of NYC).  So you can try your route with your favorite online route planner, adding each of these three bridges successively as intermediate stops, and see which route looks best.

Comment: Of these the Tappan Zee is probably the best compromise on, say, a hypothetical trip from Boston to Washington - the further north you cross, the more extra mileage you add.  The Tappan Zee may be a better choice than going through NYC even in the westbound (toll-free) direction, due to traffic.

Comment: An additional note: Pretty much all of the bridges and tunnels around NYC will give you a discount if you have an EZ-Pass (except the small number that are free anyway, like the Queensboro Bridge). In most cases it's only a few dollars, but it can add up if you go through that area frequently.

Answer (score 12):

It's simpler than you might think.

Look at the map (with tolls removed), decide which roads you do not want to travel on and use an alternative route.

A quick check of the geography shows that alternative bridges are a ways upriver, the I84 doesn't add that much time.

Comment: Rolled back to the edit @MarkMayo did as the other version is seen as 'not nice'. And that version may well get deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Nate has rightly pointed out the three bridge options for minimizing the toll expenses while traveling through NYC. Among them, the most economical would be Tappan Zee Bridge.

Say you travel between Silver Spring, MD and Amherst, MA regularly. The usual route is to take I95 through George Washington Bridge which costs around $40 in tolls whereas if you take I78 and pass through Tappan Zee Bridge, you'll save 30 bucks straight.

However, Google Maps is not good at suggesting routes like this to minimize tolls but there are plethora of trip planner apps/websites (just Google;). You can try [tollguru](https://tollguru.com/toll-calculator); have heard it is popular among New Yorkers. It shows alternate routes with varying toll charges. I calculated the above costs there only.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Andrew.  I travel between Olney, MD and Hanover, NH.  It's simple.  I put my address, with destination as Hanover, NH and then I put Tappan Zee Bridge as a "stop" and that's it.  It will avoid all the NYC stuff.  Much easier drive too.